# Amend commit while splitting in rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-amend

Sometimes I accidentally amend the previous commit with the changes I want to make to the one before that, i.e. `HEAD~1`. I usually go into rebase interactive mode with `git rebase -i`, split the commit into two commits, complete the rebase. Then rebase again to fixup the original commit

Is there a quicker way to do this? Can I just `git commit --amend` after I split the commit, adding my amend changes to the staging area before amending?

Comment: Interesting workflow. Question: how do you split the commit in the first place? I tried and succeeded, but it seemed pretty arduous to do. As for your question, I don't see a quicker way because I think what you're suggesting would require a second rebase (to squash two commits into one) in the middle of processing the first rebase, which you cannot do.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to "cherry pick" a change in your commit history to save it in a new branch, and then modify your previous commit to remove it.

Like you mentioned, that's pretty tricky from the command line. But, there are a number of tools around that make this easier. For example Git Extensions has an easy way to [modify your commit history](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modify_history.html) using it's graphical user interface instead of the command line.